How can events on the quantum-level be random but not on the macro-level?
This question has been asked before on PSE, many times, and I have looked at them. But I don't think any of them get to the crux of my question.
My chair is made up of quindecillions of atoms (not infinite). Each atom has a given probability of decaying at any given moment. This given probability is not affected by the decay of any other atoms. Therefore, there is a $>0$ probability of my chair disintegrating beneath me right as I type this.
I know that even if an atom has a very high chance of undergoing decay (say, more than $0.99999999$), when taken to the power of the number of atoms that are in the chair, the probability of the chair's sudden disintegration becomes such a small number that it can be said to be $0$.
But that's not usually how science is explained. Things are given with certain answers, not probable answers.
But no matter how small it is, the fact that it isn't zero troubles me. This means that nothing is guaranteed -- the sun's rising tomorrow, the structural integrity of a child's head -- whatever it is, there is always some nonzero chance that a chaotic event will occur. A quantum physicist has no right, therefore, to deny Moses' staff turning into a snake, for example. That's not a miracle, that's just a chaotic event with a nonzero chance of occurring. I don't want to dwell on the metaphysical, but if the cause behind each quantum event's outcome is referred to as God -- not only a first cause of the universe, but also a necessary being that sustains it and prevents chaotic events from occurring -- then it's not at all difficult to believe in these religious stories, given evidence of their authenticity.
So I guess, why don't scientists say Deo volente when referring to the outcome of a future event, where Deo is whatever determines the outcome of a quantum event -- be it truly random or otherwise? Why isn't it acknowledged that seemingly "crazy" things can happen?

Not everything is random. There is no chance, even in quantum theory, for there to be a violation of energy and momentum conservation, simply because we put it in as an ingredient to build the theory. So then a lot of crazy things cannot happen. When a chance of something crazy happening is going to take longer than the age of the universe to happen, there is no point in entertaining those possibilities. It will just make conversation horrible if you try to state predictions with alternatives of absurdly low probabilities

Galton Board

Related thread in Philosophy SE: Are there probabilistic facts of the matter about the universe? My answer there also mentions Moses.

"Things are given with certain answers, not probable answers" is false. Experimental results without error bars are worthless. "There is no chance, even in quantum theory, for there to be a violation of energy and momentum conservation" is also false. Ehrenfest's theorem is stated as an average because it would not hold otherwise.

This may a good question if cleared up, but it does not seem to be a question on physics in the strict sense appropriate for this site. Maybe try asking on https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ .

All models are wrong; some are useful
"How science is explained" is really a topic for the math & science educators stack exchange.  But if you want to look at what scientists really believe, it's that we create models.  Some of them are useful.  Some models, like Newtonian physics, are deterministic.  Others, like Quantum Physics, are stochastic in nature.  But all of them are models, and only models.  Whether or not they are actually laws of the universe is yet to be seen.  (that's a bit of a lie.  Both Newtonian physics and QM are known to fail to be predictive in some regimes, so we know both of them are just models of some yet-defined more complex universe).
As such, the question is whether a model is applicable or not.  You can indeed say "deo volente" about everything.  You can say anything you want.  But if you want to get money to build a new building, people will typically ask you to use a different model than that.  Its just not useful.  For religious questions, such as a burning bush, it may be a more applicable model.
Two details that may be of use:
Quantum mechanics does not predict arbitrary results.  It predicts stochastic results.  One can construct a QM experiment, execute it, then re-construct it and execute it again.  One expects certain trends to occur.  Indeed, if you ran a QM experiment 20 times, and each time resulted in a burning-bush level of unexpected result, it would call into question the QM model in the first place.
We also have to consider chaotic systems.  Chaotic systems are deterministic, in that a single state will deterministically to some predictable outcome, but they are exponentially sensitive to initial conditions.  There has never been a measurement without measurement error, so these small errors lead to uncertainty in result, even if the laws of the universe are deterministic.
This strongly limits the time horizon for some of the "I can't believe ----" arguments.  For instance, we cannot predict where the planets will be a million years from now.  If we cannot predict that, then we certainly wont be able to keep tabs on whether one of the quintillion atoms in a chair decomposed.  It also makes a lot of statements about the validity of the models.  In engineering, we typically take science based models and apply the uncertainties of our measurements to get stochastic predictions of what will happen.  These are independent of the concept of QM and its randomness.

Central Limit Theorem and the thermodynamic limit provide that if a variable $X$ has a certain distribution, as you take the mean of $N$ instances of the variable (energy, momentum, etc), as $N$ gets very large, the distribution of the group is normally distributed and, furthermore, all probability density is concentrated arbitrarily close to the mean value. I can't really explain it better here in brief, than suggesting you research the CLT and accompanying examples.
But another point: just because quantum mechanics provides a model of excellent precision for a single particule, or even a group of 10 particles, doesn't mean it has any validity when scaled up to a system of 10$^6$ or 10$^{23}$ particles.  It's often tacitly assumed that large systems are simply a summation of a large number of single-particle interactions described precisely by quantum mechanics, and that it is merely computational effort that prevents using this for predictions.  But the fact is there is no data to support this assertion.  That is my opinion at least.


I know that even if an atom has a very high chance of undergoing decay (say, more than 0.99999999), when taken to the power of the number of atoms that are in the chair, the probability of the chair's sudden disintegration becomes such a small number that it can be said to be 0.

Atoms in a chair don't have a high probability of decaying, they have an extremely low probability of decaying. In each second the probability of a carbon 12 atom decaying is so small nobody has ever observed it happening so a wooden or plastic chair won't disintegrate.
Also, there are plenty of kinds of events that are prohibited by quantum theory. For example, conservation laws prohibit events that involve the creation or destruction of energy or momentum:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.1802

But that's not usually how science is explained. Things are given with certain answers, not probable answers.

There are many areas of science where one can't make predictions, e.g. - you can't predict whether a given male and female tiger will decide to mate.

A quantum physicist has no right, therefore, to deny Moses' staff turning into a snake, for example.

Transforming a staff into a snake would break a lot of rules of quantum physics. It's difficult to see how it could be consistent with energy and momentum conservation, selection rules on electron transitions and nuclear transitions and so on. My suggestion if you're actually bothered by this is to read a textbook on quantum theory such as "Physics of Atoms and Molecules" by Bransden and Joachain.

I don't want to dwell on the metaphysical, but if the cause behind each quantum event's outcome is referred to as God -- not only a first cause of the universe, but also a necessary being that sustains it and prevents chaotic events from occurring -- then it's not at all difficult to believe in these religious stories, given evidence of their authenticity.

Suppose a quantum state evolves under the unitary operator $U$ to become unsharp:
$$|0\rangle\to^U\frac{1}{{\sqrt{2}}}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)$$
by say shining light at an atom for a particular amount of time. The cause of that transition is shining the light. When you observe the atom it's impossible to know what state you'll find it in because there is no single fact of the matter about that but the set of possibilities and the probability of observing each of them does have a cause: the transition described by $U$.
The weirdness of quantum theory has been overstated in many respects by bad popular science writers and obscurantist physicists. AFAICT there is no particular reason to say divine intervention is required and given how much controversy there is about events that happened in living memory on video for all to see I would be sceptical about stuff that was reported to happen thousands of years ago.

"There are many areas of science where one can't make predictions, e.g. - you can't predict whether a given male and female tiger will decide to mate."
I suppose what I meant by that was that facts are either given in certainties or probabilities, and when it is given in probabilities, the probability itself is certain. Obviously we don't have all the initial conditions, nor the functions which lead them to certain outputs, but were we to, I was under the presumption, we could determine the outcome with certainty.

On your last point, that story only appears in the Torah and the Quran -- both books that claim to be entirely the word of God. No one is relying on eyewitness accounts from ~3000 years ago, but on the truthfulness of the narrator.


How can events on the quantum-level be random but not on the
macro-level?

One aspect of the answer to this question is emergent properties. For example, we cannot assign a temperature to a single atom, but we can assign a temperature to a container of gas atoms. Temperature is an emergent quantity. If a chair has a non-zero temperature, any one of its atoms is moving randomly due to thermal noise, but when we consider the chair as a whole, we can assign a fairly definite position to the location of the chair. The individual molecules of the chair interact with each other due to electromagnetic forces, and this constrains the location of the chair to an average of all the positions of the individual molecules. This is also an emergent property of macro objects that differentiates macro objects from individual quantum particles.
Can we rule out that the container of gas randomly jumps to the right if all the molecules happen by chance to all move in the same direction at the same time? Yes, we can! At the microscopic level, any changes in the velocity of an individual molecule are due to collisions with other gas molecules and each collision is bound by the rules of conservation of momentum, so there is no sequence of collision events that can result in the total average momentum of the container becoming non zero and moving the container as a whole.

But that's not usually how science is explained. Things are given with
certain answers, not probable answers.

That is not entirely true. Chaos theory is all about our inability to predict with $100\%$ certainty the future evolution of certain systems due to our inability to measure with $100\%$ accuracy the initial conditions. This is why weather predictions are often given as probabilities, e.g. there is a $60\%$ chance of it being sunny next weekend at a given location. Medical predictions are also often given as probabilities. Life insurance companies would love to know with certainty if a given individual will still be alive $x$ years from now, but if they ask any scientist, the scientist can give an answer in terms of proximities.

But no matter how small it is, the fact that it isn't zero troubles
me. This means that nothing is guaranteed -- the sun's rising
tomorrow, the structural integrity of a child's head -- whatever it
is, there is always some non-zero chance that a chaotic event will
occur.

Uncertainty is a fact of life; we have to learn to live with it. There is a non-zero probability you will struck by a meteorite tomorrow, but the probability is so small that that is not worth living in an an underground bunker. Consider that every second, cosmic rays, decay products from background radiation and neutrinos are passing through your body. There is a small chance that one of these rays or particles hit a certain part of the DNA in a cell of your body, triggering a cancerous growth. It is not possible to guarantee an absolute zero probability of bad things happening.

So I guess, why don't scientists say Deo volente when referring to the
outcome of a future event, where Deo is whatever determines the
outcome of a quantum event -- be it truly random or otherwise? Why
isn't it acknowledged that seemingly "crazy" things can happen?

Crazy, unlikely things do occur. Scientists do acknowledge that they can happen. When they design oil rigs, they acknowledge that a crazy superwave could occur where they build the rig. They calculate what is the biggest freak wave that is likely to occur in that region every $100$ years. They design the rig to withstand such a wave. The people investing in building the rig accept the risk that their new rig might be wiped out next week by a freak wave, but they consider the risk to be small enough. There is no guarantee that the rig will not be hit by the sort of freak wave that is only supposed to happen every $200$ years, and we do not necessarily have to wait $200$ years for it to happen. In industry, safety is important, and lots of precautions are taken to try and ensure accidents do not happen, but they still happen despite our best efforts when "all the holes line up", and a sequence of unlikely events all happen at the same time. When preparing to do a job in an industry, a risk assessment is carried out. If it concludes that there is less than one in a thousand chance of someone getting injured and less than one in a million chance of someone getting killed, the job can be authorised to go ahead. The one in one million probability is the acknowledgement that crazy things happen.

A quantum physicist has no right, therefore, to deny Moses' staff
turning into a snake, for example

Statistically, it is twice as likely that half the staff will turn into half a snake and four times as likely that staff will turn into a quarter of a snake and so on. We have to ask ourselves why we do not see the inbreed cases, which are more likely. Why a snake and not a caterpillar or some other creature? Those outcomes are just as likely, but we do not see cases of staff turning into random creatures, and why a perfect snake? The chances are that the staff could turn into a six-eyed snake or a two-legged snake and myriad other imperfect versions of a snake. The chances of forming a perfectly formed living snake are much smaller than forming an imperfect snake, but we do not see cases of the more likely cases of staffs turning into imperfect snakes.
Let's say you are blindfolded and sat on a revolving chair and asked to throw darts at a dart board and try and hit the bullseye, but they also move the board. It is not impossible for you to hit the bullseye, but we would reasonably expect there to be many more cases where you hit part of the board but not the bullseye. It would indeed be strange if only one dart hit the bullseye, but all the other million random darts missed the board completely.

"...they calculate what is the biggest freak wave that is likely to occur in that region every 100 years. They design the rig to withstand such a wave..."
I have no quarrel with this. I acknowledge and respect the manner in which engineering problems are solved. I'm completely okay with approximations such as $\sin(1) = 1$ if they are deemed sufficient for the scope of the problem being solved. My issue is more related to the absolute certainty with which quantum mechanics is said to be "instrinsically probabilistic" but how no one seems to acknowledge what that entails about my chair.

I'm very confused by your last two paragraphs. So what if there is another situation that is equally, or more, likely? My point was only to show that the event has a nonzero chance of occurring, i.e., it is possible. Of course you can't be certain of it unless you believe that God was the one who revealed the book which that story is related in (I happen to, and for intellectual reasons, not blind faith). I don't really see what you're trying to say there.

A useful way to think about stuff like this is as follows:
As we "zoom out" from the quantum world to the macro world we inhabit, the individual screwy histories of quantum particles get averaged out so by the time we are talking about things like chairs and tables, that quantum evidence and unpredictability has been erased, and we are left with chairs that do not spontaneously disappear or change into tables.
Things at the macro level can be designed to possess non-probabilistic behavior (this Toyota minivan will not disappear unless someone steals it) or nearly complete probabilistic behavior (this handful of gambling die each yield a 1/6 probability of landing on any given face) but things on the quantum level cannot.

I completely understand this. But when we're speaking purely objectively, the non-probabilistic behaviour of the Toyota minivan or the die having a 1/6 probability of landing on any given face is only a useful model, not an objective reality. When I tell you I don't care about how small the chance is, I'm telling you I don't care -- the fact is, unless someone can prove me wrong, the instrinsic randomness of quantum mechanics must entail that that Toyota minivan can disappear without someone stealing it, and that a die can land on 6 all night without any foul play.

@BarackBarackBarack. try posting this on the math SE and ask one of the fine people there to help you calculate the odds.

I get you're being funny but you're also completely missing my point. I don't care about the odds whatsoever so long as they are nonzero.

Fine. then calculate the odds yourself.
